# Show that $d^T Z\sim N(d^T\mu, d^TVd)$

Tags: normal-distribution

> > Consider $Z=(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)^T\sim N(\mu,V)$ with $\mu=(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n)^T$ and $V=\text{Cov}(Z)$. Show that for $d\in\mathbb{R}^n$ it is 
> >     $$
> > d^TZ\sim N(d^T\mu,d^TVd).
> > $$

For me it is not clear how to show that $d^TZ$ is multivariate normal distributed.
If that would be the case then because of
$$
E(d^TZ)=d^TE(Z)=d^T\mu
$$
and
$$
\text{Cov}(d^TZ)=d^T\text{Cov}(Z)(d^T)^T=d^T\text{Cov}(Z)d
$$
everything would be shown.

---

I've read that $d^TZ$ is multivariate normal distributed exactly then when for each $b\in\mathbb{R}$ 
$$
bd^TZ
$$
is univariate normal distributed.

So I choose an arbitrary $b\in\mathbb{R}$ and would have to show that
$$
bd^TZ=\sum_{i=1}^{n}bd_iZ_i~~~(*)
$$
is univariate normal distributed. If the $Z_i$ were independent then it would be clear because a linear combination of independent univariate normal distributed random variables is itself univariate normal distributed.

But here the $Z_i$ are not independent, what to do now to show that (*) is univariate normal distributed?

Comment: To address your last point: if $X$ and $Y$ jointly normally, then there exists $a$ such that $Y = aX+(Y-aX)$ such that $Y-aX$ is independent of $X$. How do we find this $a$?

$Cov(X,Y-aX)  = Cov(X,Y)-a Var(X)=0$, then solve for $a$. Now generalise this for $n$ variables!

Comment: The process is a bit like Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: Sorry, do not understand why this helps.

Comment: Because you can decompose joint normals into independent normals... Because you said you want sum of independent normal increments... Covariance 0 is equivalent to independent... Never mind

Comment: So I just have to define $c:=bd$ and then $c^TZ$ is univariat normal distributed because $Z$ is multivariat normal distributed. Right?

Answer (score 1):

My Suggestion:

$Var(d^TZ)=E(d^T(Z-\mu)(Z-\mu)^Td)=d^T\cdot E((Z-\mu)(Z-\mu)^T)\cdot d$